# Firebase does not update values throughout an app until the user is logged out

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

So, I have been coming across a problem where my Firebase app does not update user values when a user makes an update. To be more clear: Lets say user 1 has a photo of a dog and then changes it to a cat.

Once they change it to a cat, my node value in Firebase is successfully updated but the user themselves won't be able to see the change in other previously loaded areas in the app (other places with the dog picture) until they log out and then log back in.

For this reason I was wondering if there was any way to conduct a background app refresh that way all previous dog values in the app are changed to cat values without the user having to log out and then log back in. Please note that this same problem occurs not only with my user's profile picture but also any other user field I have setup.

Here is how I am updating a node value for my user in Firebase:

```
        let storageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference()
        _ = FIRStorageMetadata()
        let filePath = "\(FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid)/\("userPhoto")"
        let profileImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.profilePicture.image!, 1.0)

        if let data = profileImageData {
            storageRef.child(filePath).put(data, metadata: nil){(metaData,error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                    return
                } else {

                    let downloadURL = metaData!.downloadURL()!.absoluteString

                    let userPhotoUpdateRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(self.currentUser).child("userPhoto")
                    userPhotoUpdateRef.setValue(downloadURL)
                }
            }
        }
```

If you have any questions please ask! Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase SDK for Cloud Storage provides an easy way to read file from and write files to cloud storage. It does not provide a way to monitor those files.

The easiest way to provide a monitoring approach is to write the metadata of the files to the Firebase Realtime Database. See this short section in the Storage docs for a brief mention of that: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/file-metadata#custom_metadata

When you write data to a location in the Firebase Database, all apps that are [actively monitoring that location](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write) will be instantly updated. When they get that update, you can reload the image from Cloud Storage for Firebase.